# Как лучше писать стили в react?

Tags: reactjs

Как лучше писать стили в React:

1. Можно выносить их в отдельный файл и пользоваться просто классами.
2. Использовать styled-component, который позволяет добавить логику в css. Но это приходится прописывать лишнее, и вместо класса `<div class='select-item'>`, нужно писать  или в шторме можно написать `li*6`, а тут прописывать `<Li><Li>` 6 раз вручную
3. Использовать и классы и styled-component

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать таблицы стилей со стилизованными компонентами (хотя это, очевидно, ненужно), а также использовать встроеные способы ввода глобальных стилей (такие как normalize или reset). Компоненты стилизации в самих компонентах - это лучшая практика, которую многие разработчики используют в React.